# Comparing number values as strings in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am currently trying to compare two strings which are numbers in a find query. I need to use strings because the numbers would cause an overflow in Javascript if I save them as such.
The to compared value comes via an API call and the value is inside an array:

```
    const auction = await this.findOne({
        $and: [{
            $or: [
                { 'bids.amount': amount },
                { 'bids.signature': signature },
                { 'bids.amount': { $gte: amount } }
            ]
        }, { 'tokenId': tokenId }, { 'isActive': true }]
    });
```

How would I change the query in order to handle the strings as numbers, so my comparison would actually be correct?

Comment: [see $toInt also](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)

Comment: I tried using that but did not get a good result. Also I would rather need toLong. Do you have an example query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bellow query assumes that bids is an array like
`bids=[{"amount" : "1224245" , "signature" : "234454523"} ...]`

If signature is not a number remove the `$toLong` from signature.

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$and": 
      [{"$eq": ["$tokenId", "tokenId_VAR"]},
       {"$eq": ["$isActive", true]},
       {"$reduce": 
         {"input": "$bids",
          "initialValue": false,
          "in": 
          {"$or": 
           ["$$value",
            {"$gte": [{"$toLong": "$$this.amount"}, "amount_VAR"]},
            {"$eq": [{"$toLong": "$$this.signature"}, "signature_VAR"]}]}}}]}}}])
```